# 2-connected planar graph and vertex degree

Tags: graph-theory

If $G$ is a 2-connected loopless planar graph, and for each vertex $v$ we define:
     $f(v) = (1/2) - (1/deg(v))$, where $deg(v)$ is the degree of vertex $v$,

Show that for some region $R:  \sum f(v) < 1 $, where the sum is over all vertices $v$ incident with $R$.

I'm confused about how to go about this. Some properties that could be relevant are:

- for 2-connected planar graphs, every region is bounded by a cycle
- $12 \leq \sum [6 - deg(v)]$  so  $\sum deg(v) \leq 6|V(G)| - 12$
- $\sum deg(v) = 2 |E(G)| $
- every region is clearly bounded by at least 3 edges and thus has at least 3 vertices incident to it
- for 2-connected graphs, every vertex has $deg(v) \geq 2$

  Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Let us denote the sum for a region as $$F(R) = \sum_{v\in R}f(v)$$
Consider the sum of $F$ over all regions of the graph. There are $\deg v$ faces incident with each vertex so each $f(v)$ is counted precisely $\deg v$ times.
$$\sum_{R\in G}F(R) = \sum_{v\in G} f(v)\deg v=\sum_{v\in G}\left(\frac{\deg v}{2}-1\right)$$
From the handshaking lemma, this is equal to
$$\sum_{R\in G}F(R)=|E| - |V|$$
From Euler's formula
$$|E|-|V| = |R|-2$$
where $|R|$ is the number of regions. Therefore the average of $F$ over the regions
$$\overline{F(R)} = \frac{|R|-2}{|R|}<1$$
is less than $1$. Therefore there must exist at least one region for which $F(R)$ itself is less than $1$.

Comment: thank you! the trick here was to see that there are deg(v) faces incident with each vertex. I'm assuming thats because the graph is 2-connected?

Comment: Yes, it's necessary for the graph to be 2-connected. You may want to prove that fact just to be complete.